# Can you help make the biggest quality effects library ever?

Tags: sound-design, sound-libraries, sound-effects, royalty-free

I am a very enthusiastic recordist and wanting others to join, loads of people upload to freesound but the quality is often useless where as I am encouraging people to get on board and offer a small premium at first in return for becoming a very positive resource for all things sound. As you will read from my tech blog I want my site to be a hub of information. This is not just a give me your sound library and get nothing but generate and share revenue through ads etc... I will be recording and uploading sounds regardless as this isn't everyone's cup of tea and I enjoy recording and want to make this a very attractive resource that can help give back to one and other like people giving answers away on here. Education is brilliant and it's all about giving back to receive :-)

I understand I'll get a lot of negative votes by I'm not sitting and waiting just taking action on a dream I have and will achieve even doing it all myself.

I'm interested in more feedback to this idea and what you expect from a project like this? And if you upload sounds for free else where and why...

also I can do all the admin and tagging anyway you can do as much or as little as you want. Again the work is all on my part anyway hence sharing revenue etc...

And there is no me telling you to do anything so that argument is invalid, you can do what you want this is for people who want to be a part of something. Stay with Freesound if you like, check why not do both?

So, here it is

---

The Big Sound Effects Project: http://soundcloud.com/matt-price-sound/dropbox

I am looking for collaborators, Sound Designers and Sound Enthusiasts to help me build the biggest resource for Original Quality Sound Effects on the internet and want your help. 
Simply follow these steps:

Step 1: Click The Link Below
Step 2: Upload A Sound Effect
Step 3: Enter A Few Tags And Rough Description
Step 4: Make The Licence Creative Commons
Step 5: Send a Personal Note With Your Name/Alias and Website So I Can Credit You

Then Wal-Ah I will place it and add more tags and descriptions after verifying the quality and add it to www.soundrolling.com

Large Contributors May Also Get Money Down The Line From Any Revenue the Site Generates.

So Get Started Now

Comment:   Yeah, best idea ever. 1. Let everyone else upload sound effects to which they either have copyright FOR FREE or which they aren't even allowed to share. Let them also do the tagging. 2. Profit. There's already http://www.freesound.org/ for free, community shared sound. 

Comment: Hi Matt, I understand your enthousiasm. I have setup a crowd sourced sound archive: http://www.geluidvannederland.nl 
It's a unique website focusing on the Dutch soundscape. Be prepared for a long start up phase. You are on your own, no publicity or marketing. And honestly what you're proposing is too vague and you didn't elaborate or answer any of my practical questions. What's your plan? please consider this constructive criticism not a bash down.

Comment: Feedback: What you're doing has been done "a billion times" earlier (there's not just Freesound, but loads of sites and resources). Also, the quality issue has been solved by commercial sound effects sites, where some people get paid to do quality control and ensure that what's uploaded is acceptable. You will not get anywhere without the support from some community (unless http://www.creativefieldrecording.com/2011/09/30/selling-sound-effects-how-to/) and you cannot continue to work or serve for free infinitely (unless the site's a side project).

Comment: You're also going to need a far more clearly defined business plan and legal framework if you're planning to engage in "revenue sharing" with contributors. As others have mentioned, this is all extremely vague. I'm not saying that you have a bad idea, but it needs evidence of more thought and planning than you're currently displaying.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback guys

Comment: So is it basically exactly what the Sound Collectors Club is doing? http://thesoundcollectorsclub.com

Answer (score 2):

I feel the agony of Internet Human. However, perhaps Matt is just a very enthousiastic sound recordist. 
@Matt: can you explain the setup for this project of yours? The way you're 'selling it' now doesn't invite me too share any sounds with you. 
How will you manage the upload of copyrighted/commercial recordings?
Will you be making money and how do you plan to get money to other contributors?

Eagerly awaiting...